# What am I missing with this routine to read uart data on AVR

Tags: buffer, avr, uart, c-strings

I am able to read the data fine. The data is a series of records, each ending with "\r\n" as the terminator and then the Data stream ends with a "\r\n". The first record comes in perfect but the remaining records are missing the first X number of characters. X does not change either.  Data is coming from a modem.

```
c = UART0_RxChar();
response[0]=c;
i=0;
rec=0;
while((c=UART0_RxChar()) != CR)
{
    response[i++]=c;
    while ((c=UART0_RxChar()) != CR)
    {
        response[i++]=c;

    }
    rec++;
    UART1_Printf("Record %d %s", rec, response);
    UART1_Printf("\n\n");
    memset(response,0,strlen(response));
    i=0;
    AT_ASSERT(UART0_RxChar() == LF)
}

AT_ASSERT(UART0_RxChar() == LF)
// Finished
```

Bad Data Received

```
Record 1 7854122,4,2017-04-11 00:00,2017-04-11 8:09,29342441,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,

Record 2 705-03 13:15,18958737,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,

Record 3 7,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,

Record 4 717-05-03 23:59,38580000,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,

Record 5 7,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,

Record 6 717-05-05 23:59,86340000,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,

Record 7 7,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,
```

Actual Data

```
7854122,4,2017-04-11 00:00,2017-04-11 08:09,29342441,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,
7854122,1,2017-04-11 08:09,,0,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,
7854122,4,2017-05-03 08:00,2017-05-03 13:15,18958737,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,
7854122,1,2017-05-03 13:15,2017-05-03 13:16,70332,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,
7854122,3,2017-05-03 13:16,2017-05-03 23:59,38580000,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,
7854122,3,2017-05-04 00:00,2017-05-04 23:59,86340000,TRK 23564,,,,BOL 327867,,0,0,0,0,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UART may not be reading the data fast enough to capture it all and so is dropping data

If the UART_RxChar function is using a buffer that came from interrupts writing to buffers, you may be able to increase the size of the buffers.

Comment: okay, I think this is exactly the issue but I have never set up a receive buffer on an avr. I'm researching now.

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error that is causing the first character in the buffer to remain what is was on the first read, in this case '7'.

The main problem is that the `printf()` statement is taking too long, and not allowing the `UART0_RxChar()` function to receive characters, so they are simply being overwritten.

A better approach might beis to use an interrupt handler to save the incoming chars to a buffer, then print the messages out when a buffer is full in the main loop. You might need to alternate between two buffers, so that you can be filling one while printing out the contents of the other.

The interrupt handler will have similar logic to what you have now: fill the buffer until `\cr\lf`, then set a flag for printing and switch to the other buffer. In the main loop busy wait for the flag, and print when it is set.